# Property won't refresh although I raised propertychanged

Tags: c#, wpf, inotifypropertychanged

at the moment I have a problem I'm not sure how to solve this or how to find an idea how to fix. 
I have a viewmodel that contains a child object. If I raise a command I reinitialize the ChildObject with new and add new data. After that my view updates and the new data is displayed. Sometimes (its not reproducable when) only one property is not updated anymore. There is no difference if I do this in the parent for the whole object or I do this with String.Empty. 
One property is not updated and will stay as its old value (the get method won't called). Once I was able to got this behaviour I'm not able to update it by raising this command again.

Can somebody help me and know where such behaviours can occure?

thanks,

**EDIT Sample code to make the problem visible. In this case it seem to work, but the code in my project looks quite same** 
XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication14.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Text"/>
        <Label Content="{Binding Path=Cls1.A}"/>
        <Label Content="{Binding Path=Cls1.B}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

ViewModel:

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WpfApplication14
{
    class VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public VM()
        {
        }

        private int b;

        public void doWork()
        {
            var cls2 = new Class2 { A = "XXX", B = "YYY", C = "ZZZ" };

            if (b == 3)
            {
                cls2 = new Class2 { A = "AAA", B = "BBB", C = "CCC" };
            }
            if (b == 4)
            {
                cls2 = new Class2 { A = null, B = null, C = null };
            }

            b++;
            if(b == 5)
            {
                b = 0;
            }


            Cls1 = new Class1(cls2);
            OnPropertyChange("Cls1");
        }

        public Class1 Cls1 { get; set; }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChange(string property)
        {
            if(PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Class2:

```
namespace WpfApplication14
{
    class Class2
    {
        public string A { get; set; }
        public string B { get; set; }
        public string C { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Class1:

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WpfApplication14
{
    internal class Class1 : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public Class1(Class2 x)
        {
            setCls2(x);
        }

        public Class2 cls2 { get; set; }

        public string A
        {
            get
            {
                return cls2.A;
            }
        }

        //After clicking e.g. this property stayes on the old value.
        public string B 
        {
            get
            {
                return cls2.B;
            }
        }

        public string C
        {
            get
            {
                return cls2.C;
            }
        }

        private void setCls2(Class2 x)
        {
            cls2 = x;
            OnPropertyChange("");
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChange(string property)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint in the setter (before PropertyChanged event is raised)? and in the getter ? Normally, breaking in the setter should be followed by breaking in the getter ? If that's not the case, try to have a look with snoop to check if your property has the excected value... If yes, then you have a problem, else, then you have simply switch ViewModel without noticing it

Comment: the property got the right value and will be set. See code in my question.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to tell from your sample code, but I think the problem may be here:

> If I raise a command I reinitialize the ChildObject with new and add
>   new data.

My guess is that when you create a new instance of the ChildObject class, you are not rewiring the PropertyChanged event for that new instance.  Therefore, the PropertyChanged event may be firing, but there is nothing wired to handle it.